# FLANN based Template Matching: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keypoints'

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to use FLANN based Matcher to locate objects on an application window and I'm getting the error:

```
kp1, kp2, matches = needle_img.keypoints(haystack)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keypoints'
```

In the below code, I:

1. Load the images into an `numpy.array` with `cv.imread` and return them as `image_list`
2. Generate `haystack` frames with `ImageGrab` and convert them into an `numpy.array`
3. Run template matching by calling `keypoints`

The error appears against the line: `kp1, kp2, matches = needle_img.keypoints(haystack)`

```
import queue
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import pygetwindow
import threading
import glob
from threading import Thread
from PIL import ImageGrab


# Load needle images
def loadImages(directory):
    image_list = []
    for i in directory:
        img = cv.imread(i, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image_list.append((img, i))
    return image_list

# Generate haystack frames 
def videoLoop():
    # Grab Window and find size 
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Name of Window')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img)
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return haystack

# Object Detection
def detection(image_list, haystack):
    for i in image_list:
        needle_img = i[0]
        kp1, kp2, matches = needle_img.keypoints(haystack)
        match_image = cv.drawMatches(needle_img, kp1, haystack, kp2, matches, None)
        return match_image

class Vision:
    # properties
    needle_img = None
    needle_w = 0
    needle_h = 0
    method = None

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, needle_img_path, method=cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED):
        self.needle_img = cv.imread(needle_img_path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    # Template Matching
    'code goes here, not relevant to question'

    # Keypoint Matching
    def keypoints(self, original_image, patch_size=32):
        min_match_count = 10

        orb = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=patch_size)
        keypoints_needle, descriptors_needle = orb.detectAndCompute(self.needle_img, None)
        orb2 = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=patch_size, nfeatures=2000)
        keypoints_haystack, descriptors_haystack = orb2.detectAndCompute(original_image, None)

        FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
        index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_LSH, table_number=6, key_size=12,multi_probe_level=1)
        search_params = dict(checks=50)

        try:
            flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
            matches = flann.knnMatch(descriptors_needle, descriptors_haystack, k=2)
        except cv.error:
            return None, None, [], [], None

        # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
        good = []
        points = []

        for pair in matches:
            if len(pair) == 2:
                if pair[0].distance < 0.7*pair[1].distance:
                    good.append(pair[0])

        if len(good) > min_match_count:
            print('match %03d, kp %03d' % (len(good), len(keypoints_needle)))
            for match in good:
                points.append(keypoints_haystack[match.trainIdx].pt)
    
        return keypoints_needle, keypoints_haystack, good, points

# Video loop thread
class VideoCaptureThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, result_queue: queue.Queue) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.exit_signal = threading.Event()
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self) -> None:
        while not self.exit_signal.wait(0.05):
            try:
                result = videoLoop()
                self.result_queue.put(result)
            except Exception as exc:
                print(f"Failed capture: {exc}")

# Run actual detection
def d():
    result_queue = queue.Queue()
    thread = VideoCaptureThread(result_queue=result_queue)
    thread.start()

    directory = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\*.png")
    
    while True:
        haystack = result_queue.get()
        # load images to detect 
        needle = loadImages(directory)
        # check if ready to run detection
        if detection(needle, haystack):
            print('Found something')
        else:
            continue   



# main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d()
```

Comment: Why do you have a function which does not belong to a class that takes `self` as first parameter? You should make it a global function and call as `keypoints(needle_img, haystack)` if that is your intend.

Comment: `needle_img` is a NumPy array and NumPy objects don't have 'keypoints' attribute... Burak is correct, but I suppose what you have really meant is defining: `def detection(self, image_list, haystack)`. And executing: `self.keypoints(needle_img, haystack)`. In case you want us to post an answer, please post a minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer with an MRC sample. I'm pretty sure the issue is my detection function is looking for keypoints but I'm not outputting any from my keypoints function or I'm not using them correctly. I followed the OpenCV documentation but it's a bit light on explanations for ORB as to what the lines of code actually do.